# How can we know that whether message is forwarded to the destination properly in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have configured a lambda function which forwards incoming messages to multiple endpoints. Also I have added a AWS API Gateway as a trigger, so if I invoke API gateway endpoint I can forward that message to multiple endpoints. I want to check whether the messages are been forwarded to the desired destination or not, also I want to check integrity of that message.

Can anyone suggest a proper way to check for the same apart from returning status code 200 in response.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the official [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-lambda-non-proxy-integration.html) about building an API and returning response. Basically you can return additional variables in response. Like in JS based lambda function

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    callback(null, {
        "greeting": greeting
    }); 
}
```

So can call the endpoints and validate the messages has been delivered or not and return state in form of variables. Please let me know if you have additional questions.